# Как посчитать полную стоимость 3-х книжек?

Tags: c++

Петр Петрович заказал в Интернет-магазине три книжки: телефонный справочник, стоимостью 950 руб. 50 коп., русско-английскийй разговорник, стоимостью 1250 руб. и сборник детективов Агаты Кристи, стоимостью 588 руб. 80 коп. Книги отправят Петру Петровичу почтой, наложенным платежом, который увеличивает стоимость каждой книги на 10%. Сколько всего придётся заплатить Петру Петровичу на почте, чтобы получить свой заказ? Напишите программу, вычисляющую полную стоимость покупки для любой стоимости отдельных книг.

Есть идея как написать но не получается.

```
int main() {
    int TelSpravoch = 850;
    int Razgovorink = 1050;
    int AgataKristi = 599;
    int TelSpravoch = (850,5 + 850 * 0.1);
    int Razgovorink = (1050 + 1050 * 0.1);
    int AgataKristi = (599 + 599 * 0.1);
    int sum = int 1 + int 2 + int 3;
        printf( "\n");
```

Как решить задачу?

**Обновление**

Есть идея.... только результат округлился.

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf("");
#include <stdlib.h> //setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
#include <locale.h> //LC_ALL

int main() {
    int TelSpravoch = 850.5; 
    int Razgovorink = 1050; 
    int AgataKristi = 599.9; 
    int sum = (850.5 + 850.5 * 0.1) + (1050 + 1050 * 0.1) + (599.9 + 599.9 * 0.1);
    printf("%drub\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Математику знаю. А вот в программном виде.......

Comment: ну напишите формулу которая вычислит то что вам нужно

Comment: Легче сказать чем сделать.

Comment: ну так сделайте для начала формулу, просто цены буквами замени  и напиши в коментарии как это сделать с точки зрения математики.

Comment: По-идее должно 2750,44 а получился результат 2750.

Comment: ну так integer - целочисленый тип без запятой, нужен float

Comment: Лучше `double`, откуда эта тяга к `float` в XXI веке? :) Все равно компилятор все литералы с точкой переведет в `double`, все вычисления выполнит в `double`, а потом будет округлять до `float`...  Ну, а вывод - как `printf("%lf.2 rub\n",sum)` - чтоб вывело с точностью 2 знака после точки (с копейками).

Comment: @Harry есть мнение, что float кушает в два раза меньше памяти, и присутствует на большем количестве GPU, нежели double. Отсюда и тяга к нему в 21 веке.

Comment: @gdb В *Optimized C++* Гантерот постоянно высмеивает это так называемое "общеизвестное мнение". По-моему, недаром. Тем более что там же у него написано, что `double` обычно быстрее `float`...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

Using namespace std;

int main() {
Double TelSpr = 950.5; //TelSpravoch
Double Razg = 1250; //Razgovornik
Double AK = 588.8; //AgataKristi 
Double sum = (TelSpr + TelSpr * 0.1) + (Razg + Razg * 0.1) + (AK + AK * 0.1);
Cout<<"summa="<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Все согласно условию: Справочник-950,5 руб, разговорник-1250 руб, книга Агаты Кристи- 588,8 руб, на каждый элемент цена повысилась ровно на 10%

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int TelSpravoch = 850;
    int Razgovorink = 1050;
    int AgataKristi = 599;
    double sum = (TelSpravoch + Razgovorink + AgataKristi);
    sum+=sum*0.1;
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```